# Custom Kernels on Stock ROMs?

Tags: rooting, clockworkmod-recovery, rom, kernel, stock-rom

**The General Question**: Is it possible to install custom kernels on a Rooted Stock ROM?

**The Example**: I have a Nexus 7 which I have rooted running 4.1.1 (Jelly Bean JRO03D) would it be possible to just flash a custom kernel,
say this one http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1831780,
on my stock ROM using Clockwork Recovery?

Sorry if this is obvious, but I've only really done it on custom roms, and I couldn't find a definite answer on the interwebs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to install custom kernels on stock roms. The kernel developer will usually say which roms (or types of roms) the kernel supports. If you are not sure you can try reading the kernel thread, and there will always be poeple saying things like "working great on [firmware version here]". This way you can also make sure that it will work ok on your version of the stock rom.

As for your example, yes you can flash this on your stock rom:
[xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=30753872&postcount=280)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can flash a custom kernel on your stock ROM, but it has to be the appropriate kernel i.e. it has to be the version the kernel supports. In this case you will be limited to overclocking only. However, you can download setcpu, nofrills, voltage control, cpu contol, etc to enjoy max.

Comment: You should provide links to the apps you're talking about. Also what do you mean limited to overclocking only?